# A formula for this generating function that is similar to the $qt$-Catalan numbers

Tags: partitions, generating-functions, symmetric-functions, catalan-numbers

I came up with the following conjecture:
$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} z^n \sum_{\mu \vdash n} \frac{ t^{\sum l}q^{\sum a}}{\prod (q^a - t^{l+1})(t^l - q^{a+1})} = \exp\left(\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{z^n}{n(q^n-1)(t^n-1)}\right)
$$
where each unlabeled sum and product is over the cells of the diagram of the partition, and $l$ and $a$ are the arm and leg lengths.

The coefficients on the left hand side are similar to the $qt$-[Catalan numbers](http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/MPWP/qtanalogs/catalan/definition.html#:%7E:text=The%20q%2C%20t-Catalan%20numbers%20arise%20naturally%20in%20the,and%20there%20exists%20a%20proof%20in%20the%20article) but are missing some factors.

I verified it up to order 10 computationally [(see here)](https://github.com/uberparagon/sum-over-parts-conjecture/blob/master/conj2.ipynb).

With a little work, this conjecture would prove a special case of the conjecture in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375271/a-conjecture-about-sums-over-partitions-arising-from-hilbert-scheme-of-points).

I hoping to get some ideas or tools about how to deal with things that look like this.

Comment: Not an answer, but I am curious if there is a (conjectural?) symmetric function version of your claimed equality, so that we obtain the right hand side by a plethystic substitution into power sums, and the left hand side reduces to what you have there.

Comment: You mean replace the z^n in the rhs with p_n, and then put some symmetric functions in the left hand side somehow, so that where you expand the symmetric functions in single variable z you recover the original?

Comment: I tried a bit to interpret the right hand side as a suitable specialization of the cycle index series for the species of permutations (i.e., the Frobenius character for the conjugation action of the symmetric group) but I didn't succeed.  I would have thought that writing $\frac{1}{n (1-q^n) (1-t^n)}$ as $\frac{1}{(1-q)(1-t)}(n-1)! [n-1]_q! [n-1]_t!  \frac{1}{n! [n]_q! [n]_t!}$ would be a good idea, but it seems that it isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This identity can be proved using the results in Garsia and Haiman's paper ["A Remarkable q,t-Catalan Sequence and q-Lagrange Inversion"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1022476211638). In particular theorem 3.10(e) gives
$$\sum_{\mu \vdash n} \frac{ t^{\sum l}q^{\sum a}}{\prod (q^a - t^{l+1})(t^l - q^{a+1})}=\sum_{\mu \vdash n} \frac{ t^{\sum a}q^{\sum a}}{\prod (1 - q^h)(1 - t^h)}$$
where $h=a+l+1$ denotes the usual hook length. Writing this expression in terms of principal specializations of Schur functions together with an application of the Cauchy identity gives
$$\sum_{n \ge 0} z^n \sum_{\mu \vdash n} \frac{ t^{\sum l}q^{\sum a}}{\prod (q^a - t^{l+1})(t^l - q^{a+1})}=\sum_{\mu}s_{\mu}(1,q,q^2,\dots)s_{\mu}(z,zt,zt^2,\dots)=\prod_{i,j\geq 0}\frac{1}{1-q^it^jz}$$
and it remains to notice that
$$\prod_{i,j\geq 0}\frac{1}{1-q^it^jz}=\exp\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i,j\geq 0} q^{ni}t^{nj}z^n\right)=\exp\left(\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{z^n}{n(q^n-1)(t^n-1)}\right)$$
as desired.

Comment: I had started to read some Garsia and Haiman papers, but I hadn't quite figured out which part I needed. I'll take a look at this!

Comment: To get the principal specializations of Schur functions, we use the Stanley Hook Content theorem?

Comment: @Drew You can also find it in section I.3 of Macdonald's book on symmetric functions and Hall polynomials (example 2).